# how to mark/check a checkbox in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have a lot of checkboxes and their names are generated with the help of the resource id they are associated with, which in turn is fetched from the database.

`$mform->addElement('checkbox', 'incres'.$coursename.$sec->section.$record3->instance);`

The second parameter is the name of the checkbox.

I need to know how to mark this checkbox as checked.I have a feeling this can be done by the setDefault method but I cant figure out how. I tried

`$mform->setDefault('reqdres'.$coursename.$sec->section.$record3->instance,1);`

But that doesnt work. I dont wish to use Javascript or the advancecheckbox element for this since that will require me doing a lot of changes in other dependant modules

Comment: In your example, the ids don't match ('incres' on the first line and 'reqdres' on the second). Maybe is it the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [Advanced Check Box](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_Form_Definition#advcheckbox)? $mform->setDefault() should work with this.